# How to access array of maps in c++

Tags: c++

I have a array of maps in the following form:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> result[SIZE]
```

I need help in accessing the values inside this map. For example, my map has values such as

```
TABLE->employee
ATTRIBUTE->name,age,salary,..
```

Comment: Not surprisingly, it is a combination of accessing an element in an array and accessing an element in a map.

Comment: You state "inside *this* map", but it is SIZE different MAPs.  Are you assuming that keys are unique across ALL maps inside result[] array by saying "this" map?  It's actually SIZE different, completely independent maps.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through all `map`s in the array, something like:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    auto it = result[i].find(value);
    if (it != result[i].end() {
          // you've found value in result[i] at iterator it 
    }
}
```